# Как вывести Dictionary в TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf

Как вывести `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` в TreeView. wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TreeView Name="treeView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}">
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Key}" />
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding }"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

treeView1.DataContext = dictionary;
```